# jQuery Check if String Contains Word

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an application where you can click on user names to add them to the reply list.
If the username is already added, it doesn't add their username again.
The problem I'm having is that if the user @assassin is added, and I try to add the user @ass, it finds @ass-assin and thinks that @ass is already added.
Here's my code:

```
$('#mentions a.mention_user').live('click', function(e){if($('textarea#message').val().toLowerCase().search('@'+$(this).text().toLowerCase()) < 0){
        $('textarea#message').val('@'+$(this).text()+' '+$('textarea#message').val());
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The text it'll be matching the usernames against will look similar to this: @user @joe @adam this is a message @someone

Comment: You need to be doing a "whole word" or "whole username" search so you don't match any partial matches.  Since we don't know what your data looks like that you're searching, it's a little hard to recommend the best way to do that.

Comment: You don't need to copy the answer into your question: once you've accepted an answer it always appears immediately after the question.

Comment: The reason I put a copy in my question is because there was a small error in the version Andy Baird provided, and I didn't want anyone else to use an answer with errors. The answer is now corrected, so I guess I'll remove it from my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the space character is illegal for usernames.
Split the textarea message string into arrays delimited by space and check each array element against the proposed username.

```
$('#mentions a.mention_user').live('click', function(e) { 
    if ($.inArray('@'+$(this).text(),$('textarea#message').val().split(' '))) { 
        $('textarea#message').val('@'+$(this).text()+' '+$('textarea#message').val()); 
    }
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Awesome, works great. You did make 2 small errors though. Correct version added to question.

Comment: Cool -- I edited my answer to display the correct version as well.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the length of the item being added to the length of the item matched.  If the lengths are equal, the item being added is already there.

Comment: The lengths are always going to be identical because I'll only be measuring the length of the item that got matched.
Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Bit hard to test without your full code, but searching by Regular Expression, and making sure it has a character that isn't A-Z, a-z, 0-9 (and any other valid username character) after it might do the trick.

Something like:

```
$('#mentions a.mention_user').live('click', function(e){if(($('textarea#message').val().toLowerCase() + ' ').search(
    new RegExp("'@'+$(this).text().toLowerCase() + '[^A-Za-z0-9\-_]')
) < 0){
        $('textarea#message').val('@'+$(this).text()+' '+$('textarea#message').val());
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: The other way that's even easier is to search with your separator - e.g. search for "@assassin " or "@assassin," or "@assassin;". Obviously only works if you have a consistent separator, and append one to the source string before you search.

Comment: I thought about that, but if it were the last username, and it didn't have anything afterwards, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @skimberk1 - it can work with the last username: note that SpoonNZ said to "append one [separator] to the source string before you search".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the separator is always a space character, you can do this:

```
$('#mentions a.mention_user').live('click', function(e){
   var taMsg = $('#message'),
       userName = '@'+$(this).text()+' ';
   if( (taMsg.val().toLowerCase() + ' ').indexOf(userName) != -1) {
      taMsg.val(userName + taMsg.val());
   }
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

The idea is if you add a space to the end of the list of usernames then you can search it for a particular username with a space after it.

I've also updated the code to cache the jQuery object for the message textarea, rather than repeating it three times. Note that if you are selecting with an id like '#message' then (given that id is unique) you don't need the 'textarea' prefix.

Also since you're not actually using a regex I've switched to `.indexOf()` instead of `.search()`.